# Cannot pickle lambda function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, dill

Using `dill` pickling of lambda functions work fine in Python 2, but not in Python 3, is there any alternative?

Python 3:

```
import dill 
import pickle
pickle.dumps(lambda x: x**2)
```

> pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle  at
>   0x104e97840>: attribute lookup  on **main** failed

Python 2.7:

```
import dill
import pickle
pickle.dumps(lambda x: x**2)
```

> cdill.dill\n_create_function\np0\n(cdill.dill\n_load_type\np1\n(S'CodeType'\np2\ntp3\nRp4\n(I1\nI1\nI2\nI67\nS'|\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x13S'\np5\n(NI2\ntp6\n(t(S'x'\np7\ntp8\nS''\np9\nS''\np10\nI1\nS''\np11\n(t(ttp12\nRp13\nc__main__\n__dict__\ng10\nNN(dp14\ntp15\nRp16\n.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like in python 2, dill replaces `pickle` when you import. In python 3, you have to use dill directly instead.

This works in python 3.5:

```
>>> import dill 
>>> dill.dumps(lambda x: x**2)
b'\x80\x03cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x01K\x00K\x01K\x02KCC\x08|\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x13Sq\x05NK\x02\x86q\x06)X\x01\x00\x00\x00xq\x07\x85q\x08X\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>q\tX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\nK\x01C\x00q\x0b))tq\x0cRq\rc__builtin__\n__main__\nh\nNN}q\x0etq\x0fRq\x10.'
```

Alternatively you can also `import dill as pickle`

```
>>> import dill as pickle 
>>> pickle.dumps(lambda x: x**2)
```

Answer (score 16):

I'm the `dill` author.

You can use `dill` in `python3` without using `dill` directly... however, it's not as nice as in `python2` just yet.

```
>>> import dill
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle._dumps(lambda x:x*x)
b'\x80\x03cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x01K\x00K\x01K\x02KCC\x08|\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x14Sq\x05N\x85q\x06)X\x01\x00\x00\x00xq\x07\x85q\x08X\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>q\tX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\nK\x01C\x00q\x0b))tq\x0cRq\rc__main__\n__dict__\nh\nNN}q\x0etq\x0fRq\x10.'
```

You'll note the `_dumps`.  Maybe you think that's weird.  It is. It's because in `python3`, `pickle` has been merged with module that used to be called `cPickle`.  Oddly:

1. `import _pickle` gives you the old `cPickle` module
2. `import pickle` gives you the `pickle` module, with `cPickle` merged in
3. `pickle.dumps` is just `_pickle.dumps`  (i.e. it's `cPickle`)
4. `pickle._dumps` is the old `pickle.dumps` function

Confusing?  The crux of it is: `pickle.dumps` is coded in `C`.  The `2.x` version of `pickle.dumps` was coded in python, but now it's been replaced by what was `cPickle.dumps`.  If you want to get to the "old" version, you can... it's `pickle._dumps`.

When you `import dill`, `dill` automatically registers all objects it knows how to serialize to the the `pickle` serialization table -- the `python` one, not the `C` one.  So, in `python3`, that means the one connected to `pickle._dumps`.

I suggest using `dill.dumps` directly instead.

```
>>> dill.dumps(lambda x:x*x)
b'\x80\x03cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x01K\x00K\x01K\x02KCC\x08|\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x14Sq\x05N\x85q\x06)X\x01\x00\x00\x00xq\x07\x85q\x08X\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>q\tX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\nK\x01C\x00q\x0b))tq\x0cRq\rc__builtin__\n__main__\nh\nNN}q\x0etq\x0fRq\x10.'
```

I'd like to try to get the `C` table to work eventually...

Comment: I can't import dill.  I'm using python 3.6 and I can import pickle but when I import dill I get module not found error

Comment: actually i spoke to soon. i pip installed dill but i'm still getting a module not found error.

Comment: check to see that your `pip` is pointing to the same `python` you are trying to use.